# Auto Layout xcode 8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode8

I'm new to IOS App Development and I'm watching this course called "IOS9 and swift 2: from beginner to professional" where he is using xCode 7 beta or Xcode 6 beta not sure and right now I am using Xcode 8 beta and I can't resize the iPhone screen in "Main.storyboard" to "inferred" as he is.

I don't even have the size option on the right side of xCode (Yes I do know how to open and close those extra things like the de bugger and stuff)

Comment: "infrared"? That sounds like a really cool version of Xcode he's using! Can I get "gamma-ray"????

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need to make this change, because "inferred" is the default. But just in case you do, this screen shot shows where it is in Xcode 8. Make sure everything is selected exactly as I show it:

[image]

Comment: see i don't have that simulated metrics at all mine starts from "view"

Comment: Because you didn't do what my screen shot shows you. Look carefully. Look very carefully. Remember, I said "Make sure everything is selected exactly as I show it." You are failing to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using inferred sizing. It will come back to bite you once you build something slightly more complex.

What you can do is use the "vary for traits" option which would dictate exactly how the application would look like in different iOS screens.

But, if that is what you really want to do, the answer above is perfectly fine!